# Dart - if statement executing even if the condition is false

Tags: dart

I just started learning Dart and while doing an exercise I got stuck.The program is executing the 'if' statement even if its false.The code is given below.

```
void main() {
var x = 'hello';

  if (x is int) {
   int y = 0;
   y = x % 2;
   print("Integer");
   switch (y) {
     case 0:
      print("Even");
      break;

     case 1:
      print("Odd");
      break;

     default:
      print("Unknown");
    }
  } 

 else if (x is double) {
  print("Decimal");
  } 

 else {
  print("String");
  }
}
```

The error shown in console is:

Error: The method '%' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '%'.
    y = x%2;
         ^

Its working perfectly for any integer but not for strings or decimal values.

Though if I am doing this ,the code works perfectly for all the values(integer,string and decimal).

```
void main() {
var x = 'hello';

if (x is int) {
 print("Integer");
 } 

else if (x is double) {
 print("Decimal");
 } 

else {
 print("String");
 }
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: replace "y = x % 2;" with "y = int.parse(x) % 2;"

Answer (score 2):

This error is emitted during *compilation* time, not during runtime.  It doesn't matter that `x is int` is never true.  This would be similar to code like:

```
if (false) {
  this is a syntax error
}
```

and you'd still expect a compilation error.

In this case, the Dart compiler already knows that `x` is of type `String` (via type inference) and that `%` is not defined on that type. (Arguably since the compiler knows that the condition is always false, it could ignore the entire `if` block.  You also could argue that reporting errors earlier is better, and that's what the Dart compiler does here.)

If you change the type of `x` to explicitly make it `dynamic` or `Object`, then your code will compile, and you will get the runtime behavior that you expect.

Comment: Making x dynamic worked.
   dynamic x = 'hello';

Much obliged for the quick response.thanks :)